# Json import error in Jmeter

Tags: arrays, json, import, jmeter, automated-tests

i need to do an assertion in Jmeter and for that i have this code:

```
import com.eclipsesource.json.*;

{
    Long maxId = -1L; 
    JsonArray subBalances = vars.get("subBalanceArray").get("subBalances").asArray();

       for (int j = 0; j < subBalances.size(); j++) 
            {
                JsonObject subBalance = subBalances.get(j).asObject();
                long subBalanceId = subBalance.get("subBalanceId").asLong();
                maxId = Math.max(maxId, subBalanceId);
            }
}

vars.put("latestId", String.valueOf(accountId.getLong("subBalanceId")));
log.info(vars.get("latestId");
```

But i get this error and i dont get it since i`m already importing all of the json functions and i have the jars in jmeter/lib. Any ideas? Thank you!

```
Assertion failure message: org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: 
Error invoking bsh method: eval Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``import 
com.eclipsesource.json.*; import org.json.JSONObject; import org.json.JSO . . 
. '' : Typed variable declaration : Class: JsonArray not found in namespace
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to download [mininal-json](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.eclipsesource.minimal-json/minimal-json/0.9.5) jar, put it under [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath) and restart JMeter to pick the .jar up. After that your code should start working as expected.

---

Also consider moving from Beanshell to Groovy as:

- [Groovy performs much better than Beanshell](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)
- [Groovy has built-in JSON support](http://groovy-lang.org/json.html) so you won't have to rely on external libraries